# Questions about the c++ constructors

Tags: c++

I ran into a code yesterday, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class test {
public:
    test()
    {
        printf("This is test's construct\n");
    }

    ~test()
    {
        printf("This is test's destroy\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t(); // no output
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this program, no output

But if I change

```
test t();
```

into

```
test t;
```

the output is as follows

```
This is test's construct
This is test's destroy
```

So I want to ask why the first example has no output?

Comment: `test t();` declares a function returning a test object. Some info here: [https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/)

Comment: And compiling with proper warnings enabled should have flagged it. At least I know clang will warn about this. I am under the impression that gcc is less capable here.

Answer (score 2):

```
test t();
```

is a declaration of a function named `t` that takes no arguments and returns a `test` object.

```
test t;
```

defines an object `t`, and calls its default constructor.

In general, prefer to initialize objects like this:

```
test t{};
```

so that you avoid any ambiguities.